# Separating firstname surname

Tags: sql-server

If the original field looks like paul@yates then this syntax picks out the surname correctly

```
  substring(surname,CHARINDEX('@',surname+'@')+1,LEN(name3))
```

however if the field is paul@b@yates then the surname looks like @b@yates. I want the middle letter to be dropped so it picks only the surname out.
any ideas?

Comment: Please reconsider storing the name fields seperate. How will you handle spaces in the last name? maiden names? prefixes? suffixes?

Comment: Why on earth is your data full of `@`s? And, if you need to deal with name parts separately, why are they not stored as separate columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can;

```
;with T(name) as (
    select 'paul@yates' union
    select 'paul@b@yates'
)
select 
    right(name, charindex('@', reverse(name) + '@') - 1) 
from T

>>

yates
yates
```

Answer (score 0):

you could reverse the array, split it till you find the first "@", take that part and reverse it again.

if this is java, there should be an array.reverse function, otherwise you possibly need to write it on your own.

also you could cut the string in pieces until there are no mor "@" signs left and then take the last part (the substring should return "-1" or something), but i like my first idea better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for you

```
declare @t table (name varchar(max));
insert @t select
'john' union all select
'john@t@bill' union all select
'joe@public';

select firstname=left(name,-1+charindex('@',name+'@')),
       surname=case when name like '%@%' then
         stuff(name,1,len(name)+1-charindex('@',reverse(name)+'@'),'')
         end
from @t;

-- results

FIRSTNAME   SURNAME
john    (null)
john    bill
joe public
```